# How to use curl to get a file from a specific directory?

Tags: linux, curl, etc

I'm working on the VulnBox ***DriftingBlues 7***. I'm trying to figure out how to `curl` from, for example, /etc. I can't figure out the syntax though. I'm trying to do something like this: `curl http://vuln.box.ip:port/etc/shadow`. I'd appreciate any tips.

Comment: Does the result of your command satisfy you? This command gets `etc/shadow` relative to the web server's document root. If that's what you want, you are done. If you want the absolute path `/etc/shadow` on a Linux system, that system must run a web server whose document root is `/`. Which is rather unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

to get files from specific directories with curl, use the `file://` protocol, for example, to get the `passwd` file from the `/etc/` directory, use

```
curl file:///etc/passwd
```